# Scala-IDE References search in Workspace/Project/Hierarchy

Tags: scala-ide

I am working on a financial app development in Scala (2.9.0-1) full time in IntelliJ 10.5 last few month and looking into moving to eclipse-ide on and off a few times.

One show stopper has been that class or method reference search by "Reference -> Workspace/Project/Hierarchy".

I have been trying to see if the reference search is working Whenever there is a new version of Scala-IDE out there.
But I get "The Operation Unavailable on the current select. Please select a valid Java element name" (I selected a class defined in scala when I had this popup)

Has anyone solved this issue?

Dev environment

- scala: 2.9.0-1
- eclipse: 3.7
- scala-ide: 2.0.0.beta10-2_09-201109130916-d64e014
- m2eclipse: the latest from http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e
- m2eclipse-scala: 0.2.3

My project is defined in maven and imported into scala-ide

Best
BG KO

Answer (score 1):

Find references is not yet implemented in Scala IDE. We are working on it and expect to get it in the first milestone for version 2.1 (rougly 6 weeks from now).

However, you can get a bit farther by using the Java Search window (Ctrl-H) and entering the name of the qualified name of the class or method that you want to search for. It doesn't always work though, so the feature is officially unsupported (work in progress).

Comment: http://scala-ide.org/blog/scala-ide-roadmap.html such a shame that IDE support is always lagging, but I appreciate it's tough work

Comment: Until Scala Search gets underway, I found [InstaSearch](http://code.inf.unibz.it/projects/instasearch/) a great plugin.

Scala Search is under [active development](https://twitter.com/mads_hartmann/status/268710711050522624), so expect significant improvements in a couple next months.

Comment: Still getting that error message as of "Build id: 3.0.2-vfinal-20131028-1923-Typesafe".